# Publisher inside a Publisher does not trigger SwiftUi re-render

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I made a "State" Object for my App in EnvironmentObject
Like this:

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var counter = Counter()
}
```

To add this to my App I use:

```
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(state))
```

The counter is a background task

```
class Counter: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var amount: Double
    
    var timer = Timer()
    
    init() {
        self.amount = 0.0
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(setCoords), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    @objc private func setCoords() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async() { () -> Void in
            self.amount = self.amount + 0.1
            print(self.amount)
        }
    }  
}
```

And in my View I have:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var state: AppState
    @State var isVisible = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.isVisible.toggle()
            }) {
               Text("Button")
            }
            if isVisible {
                Text(state.counter.amount.description)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically, what I was hoping was that I see the counter in my UI update after every second. But the UI does not update. I see the print statement fire every second and if I trigger the UI update from the UI Button `self.isVisible.toggle()` then the counter will also update.

How could I solve this problem without moving the counter into the View or implementing it in the state object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is not correct. You made `Counter` as `ObservableObject`, but never observe it.

Making `state` as `@EnvironmentObject` you observe changes of property `var counter`, but not inside it. It is class, reference type, not struct, so modifications of internal properties of instance does not result in modification of the instance itself - the reference remains the same, so `state` is not changed.

Here is one of the approach to make your snapshot working - by introducing explicit publisher events observing and update dependent local view state:

```
@State var currentCounter: String = ""
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            self.isVisible.toggle()
        }) {
           Text("Button")
        }
        if isVisible {
            Text(currentCounter)
            .onReceive(state.counter.$amount, perform: { value in
                self.currentCounter = value.description
            })
        }
    }
}
```